# Best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, rss, atom-feed

I'm currently using [Magpie RSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) but it sometimes falls over when the RSS or Atom feed isn't well formed. Are there any other options for parsing RSS and Atom feeds with PHP?

Comment: There is one problem with this request most Feed readers are using php's core XML readers and if the XML is not Well-Formatted as required by the XML standards it will fall over you could look at ones that don't use XML readers and use a Text Reader however the load on the server will dramatically increase.

I know this is answered i'm just making people aware of the drawbacks of using XML feed readers

Comment: Never try to parse invalid XML. Blame the source.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your other options include:

- [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/)
- [Last RSS](http://lastrss.oslab.net/)
- [PHP Universal Feed Parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4548-PHP-Parse-RSS-and-ATOM-feeds.html)

Comment: Zend Feed http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html

Comment: I don't like such "answers", giving links without any comments. Looks like you google it and link to a few top results. Especially since the asker has some RSS experience and needs a *better* parser.

Comment: In case somebody needs a little bit advice, Last RSS is the easiest among the three listed above. Only 1 file to "require", and can fetch the RSS within 5 lines, with a decent array output.

Comment: picoFeed https://github.com/fguillot/picoFeed

Comment: I've used two of them and LastRss seems not good enough providing a fully functional helper and SimplePie is a bit too complicated. I would like to try some others but comments to those libs are better for people to understand, not just links.

Answer (score 174):

I've always used [the SimpleXML functions built in to PHP](https://www.php.net/simplexml) to parse XML documents. It's one of the few generic parsers out there that has an intuitive structure to it, which makes it extremely easy to build a meaningful class for something specific like an RSS feed. Additionally, it will detect XML warnings and errors, and upon finding any you could simply run the source through something like HTML Tidy (as ceejayoz mentioned) to clean it up and attempt it again.

Consider this very rough, simple class using SimpleXML:

```
class BlogPost
{
    var $date;
    var $ts;
    var $link;

    var $title;
    var $text;
}

class BlogFeed
{
    var $posts = array();

    function __construct($file_or_url)
    {
        $file_or_url = $this->resolveFile($file_or_url);
        if (!($x = simplexml_load_file($file_or_url)))
            return;

        foreach ($x->channel->item as $item)
        {
            $post = new BlogPost();
            $post->date  = (string) $item->pubDate;
            $post->ts    = strtotime($item->pubDate);
            $post->link  = (string) $item->link;
            $post->title = (string) $item->title;
            $post->text  = (string) $item->description;

            // Create summary as a shortened body and remove images, 
            // extraneous line breaks, etc.
            $post->summary = $this->summarizeText($post->text);

            $this->posts[] = $post;
        }
    }

    private function resolveFile($file_or_url) {
        if (!preg_match('|^https?:|', $file_or_url))
            $feed_uri = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/shared/xml/'. $file_or_url;
        else
            $feed_uri = $file_or_url;

        return $feed_uri;
    }

    private function summarizeText($summary) {
        $summary = strip_tags($summary);

        // Truncate summary line to 100 characters
        $max_len = 100;
        if (strlen($summary) > $max_len)
            $summary = substr($summary, 0, $max_len) . '...';

        return $summary;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have an end-tag with no start tag. ;)

Comment: Well, I had one, but it was being eaten by SO's code formatter since it had no empty line above it. On a related note, you did not start your sentence with a capital letter. ;)

Comment: Please change `$feed_uri = $feed_or_url;` to `$feed_uri = $file_or_url;` ... other than that, thank you for this code!  It works great!

Comment: Note that while this solution is great, it'll only parse RSS feeds in it's current form. Atom feeds will not be parsed due to their different schema.

Comment: Note that `eregi_replace` is now deprecated and has been replaced with `preg_replace` as well as `eregi` with `preg_match`. Documentations can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) respectively.

Comment: I don't understand what is `cookHtmlSummarySoup()` for? whay not use `strip_tags()`?

Comment: @ITSAlaska Thanks for the reminder. I think even back when I posted this in 2008 it was old code. I've updated it with preg_match accordingly.

Comment: @vladkras Good question. Not sure where that wacky method name came from, looks like someone here edited it. I much prefer a built-in, so I've updated this to use strip_tags(). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 48):

With 4 lines, I import a rss to an array.

```
$feed = implode(file('http://yourdomains.com/feed.rss'));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

For a more complex solution

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
 $feed->load('file.rss');
 $json = array();
 $json['title'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
 $json['description'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
 $json['link'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
 $items = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('item');

 $json['item'] = array();
 $i = 0;

 foreach($items as $key => $item) {
 $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
 $description = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
 $pubDate = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
 $guid = $item->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;

 $json['item'][$key]['title'] = $title;
 $json['item'][$key]['description'] = $description;
 $json['item'][$key]['pubdate'] = $pubDate;
 $json['item'][$key]['guid'] = $guid; 
 }

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: I just tried it. It does not give an array

Comment: can u give me the rss feed that u are using?

Comment: In case you're wondering. It looks like he's using a tumblr rss feed. Anytumblrsite.com/rss would give you the same output.

Comment: Used the 4 lines, did a great job :) but then I rewrote the 1st line : `$feed = file_get_contents('http://yourdomains.com/feed.rss');` _might be less intensive than file + implode_

Comment: one line, 
$feed = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_file('http://news.google.com/?output=rss')), true);

Comment: i really like the one-liner - was looking for something like that - what about error-handling?

Comment: Why on earth are we converting an object into an array???

Answer (score 27):

I would like introduce simple script to parse RSS:

```
$i = 0; // counter
$url = "http://www.banki.ru/xml/news.rss"; // url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser

// RSS items loop

print '<h2><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="'.$rss->channel->image->url.'" /> '.$rss->channel->title.'</h2>'; // channel title + img with src

foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
if ($i < 10) { // parse only 10 items
    print '<a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a><br />';
}

$i++;
}
```

Comment: Clear and simple solution! Works nicely.

Comment: rather than using $xml = simplexml_load_string($feed), this works pretty simple, in printing the data too ...

Answer (score 13):

If feed isn't well-formed XML, you're supposed to reject it, no exceptions. You're entitled to call feed creator [a bozo](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2004/01/11/PostelPilgrim).

Otherwise you're paving way to mess that HTML ended up in.

Comment: +1, you should not try to work around any XML that is not well-formed. We've had bad experiences with them, trust me, it was big pain :(

Comment: However, programmers do not get to choose business partners and have to parse what they are given.

Comment: What if you're building an universal RSS/Atom feed reader ? If any ill-formed xml file can "mess" your HTML, who is the Bozo ? ;) Be liberal in what you receive.

Answer (score 6):

The HTML Tidy library is able to fix some malformed XML files. Running your feeds through that before passing them on to the parser may help.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) to parse a Google Reader feed and it works pretty well and has a decent feature set.

Of course, I haven't tested it with non-well-formed RSS / Atom feeds so I don't know how it copes with those, I'm assuming Google's are fairly standards compliant! :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use BNC Advanced Feed Parser- i like the template system that is very easy to use

Answer (score 1):

The PHP RSS reader - http://www.scriptol.com/rss/rss-reader.php - is a complete but simple parser used by thousand of users...

Answer (score -3):

Another great free parser - http://bncscripts.com/free-php-rss-parser/
It's very light ( only 3kb ) and simple to use!

Comment: cant say its "great" using gzinflate and base64_decode, typically disabled for security.

Comment: it's a dead link for marketing porpuses.