# Grabbing data from a text file in a "line per line" manner - and sending those into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have a data similar like this, written in a single text file..

BOX,12

CAN,99

.... and so on.

Now I want to execute those into mysql tables using explode() what will not be a problem.

**But anyway, any ideas how can I grab row per row (line per line) from a text file into PHP?**

Comment: [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) — Reads entire file into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it like this:

```
$lines = file('my/file/text.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . $line . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
// Trying to open TXT file
if( $file = fopen('file.txt', 'r') )
{
    // Loop until the End Of File
    while( ! feof($file) )
    {
        // Get current line
        $line = fgets($file);

        echo $line . '<br />';
    }

    // Closing TXT file
    fclose($file);
}
else
    echo 'fopen() fail';
```

For more detais about the functions:

[fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) 
[feof()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php) 
[fgets()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) 
[fclose()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

Comment: $arquivo should be replaced with $file and that does it. Thx :) ps: please be patient few mins to accept answer ;)

Comment: @Xfile, Sorry, i forgot to translate from Portuguese =). I've updated the answer now.

Comment: Thx to you too Marco! It was hard for me to select better answer but ill be using those of Anzicourt. Thx to both of you :)))

Comment: @Xfile, No problem, Azincourt gave a nice solution. Take care only about the file size, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749441/php-fastest-way-possible-to-read-contents-of-a-file)

Comment: @ Marcio Simao - Thank you very much Marcio for that link:) Usually data which I insert via this solution are small, but that link is very handy for other tasks in the future. Thx :)