# Handle errors of file_get_contents()

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using the [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parser to parse URL contents.

It contains the following line of code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
```

`file_get_contents` returns a warning when the URL does not exist. How can I handle all possible errors for such case, i.e. 404 and all other possible errors.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.something-not-valid-bla-bla-1234.com/): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in simple_html_dom.php on line 76
```

Comment: i would not do with either of the answers below suggest, i would start by switching to curl, then handling its for more meingful output in a more intelligent way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an `@` in front of `file_get_contents` and then check if `$contents === false;`

```
$contents = @file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
if ($contents === false) {
  //Something went wrong.
}
```

EDIT: The `@` suppresses the error from being dumped out.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do them this way, ( single assignment )

```
if( false === ( $contents = @file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset))) {
  //Something went wrong.
}
```

Also take note of the strict === equality operator as opposed to just ==

@Update I agree with Dagon about cUrl, as you are accessing content -via- a url, even using file_get_contents may not work depending on your php settings. for further info I found this related question, the explanation is quite a bit lengthy tho and would require some changes in the implementation.

[Get content from a url using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176180/get-content-from-a-url-using-php)