# How to convert an RSS XML feed in to array using PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I hope the title means all :-)

**How to convert an RSS XML feed in to array using PHP**

How can this be done...

For example: I am using the below URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=AIzaSyBnjn7hr6Zok78f35Q49Od-3wtTYeVH3NI&country=US&q=digital+camera&alt=atom

This results in XML pattern. **I am in need to convert this in to array format using PHP.**

Any help will be thankful and grateful.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Do you mind using external libraries like ZF?

Comment: Please point out which of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+rss+php you have checked before asking and why they didnt help solve your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

Step by Step

[`How to Read an RSS Feed With PHP`](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-read-an-rss-feed-with-php-screencast/)

```
<?php

function getFeed($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

---

```
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
```

---

```
echo "<ul>";

foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
    echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

[`XML to Array in PHP`](http://mysrc.blogspot.com/2007/02/php-xml-to-array-and-backwards.html)

```
/*
    Working with XML. Usage: 
    $xml=xml2ary(file_get_contents('1.xml'));
    $link=&$xml['ddd']['_c'];
    $link['twomore']=$link['onemore'];
    // ins2ary(); // dot not insert a link, and arrays with links inside!
    echo ary2xml($xml);
*/

// XML to Array
function xml2ary(&$string) {
    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $string, $vals, $index);
    xml_parser_free($parser);

    $mnary=array();
    $ary=&$mnary;
    foreach ($vals as $r) {
        $t=$r['tag'];
        if ($r['type']=='open') {
            if (isset($ary[$t])) {
                if (isset($ary[$t][0])) $ary[$t][]=array(); else $ary[$t]=array($ary[$t], array());
                $cv=&$ary[$t][count($ary[$t])-1];
            } else $cv=&$ary[$t];
            if (isset($r['attributes'])) {foreach ($r['attributes'] as $k=>$v) $cv['_a'][$k]=$v;}
            $cv['_c']=array();
            $cv['_c']['_p']=&$ary;
            $ary=&$cv['_c'];

        } elseif ($r['type']=='complete') {
            if (isset($ary[$t])) { // same as open
                if (isset($ary[$t][0])) $ary[$t][]=array(); else $ary[$t]=array($ary[$t], array());
                $cv=&$ary[$t][count($ary[$t])-1];
            } else $cv=&$ary[$t];
            if (isset($r['attributes'])) {foreach ($r['attributes'] as $k=>$v) $cv['_a'][$k]=$v;}
            $cv['_v']=(isset($r['value']) ? $r['value'] : '');

        } elseif ($r['type']=='close') {
            $ary=&$ary['_p'];
        }
    }    

    _del_p($mnary);
    return $mnary;
}

// _Internal: Remove recursion in result array
function _del_p(&$ary) {
    foreach ($ary as $k=>$v) {
        if ($k==='_p') unset($ary[$k]);
        elseif (is_array($ary[$k])) _del_p($ary[$k]);
    }
}

// Array to XML
function ary2xml($cary, $d=0, $forcetag='') {
    $res=array();
    foreach ($cary as $tag=>$r) {
        if (isset($r[0])) {
            $res[]=ary2xml($r, $d, $tag);
        } else {
            if ($forcetag) $tag=$forcetag;
            $sp=str_repeat("\t", $d);
            $res[]="$sp<$tag";
            if (isset($r['_a'])) {foreach ($r['_a'] as $at=>$av) $res[]=" $at=\"$av\"";}
            $res[]=">".((isset($r['_c'])) ? "\n" : '');
            if (isset($r['_c'])) $res[]=ary2xml($r['_c'], $d+1);
            elseif (isset($r['_v'])) $res[]=$r['_v'];
            $res[]=(isset($r['_c']) ? $sp : '')."</$tag>\n";
        }

    }
    return implode('', $res);
}

// Insert element into array
function ins2ary(&$ary, $element, $pos) {
    $ar1=array_slice($ary, 0, $pos); $ar1[]=$element;
    $ary=array_merge($ar1, array_slice($ary, $pos));
}
```