# Put another website's RSS feed into my website

Tags: php, html, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display RSS feeds from other sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615635/how-to-display-rss-feeds-from-other-sites)

**What I want:** I want a "news feed" on my website. This feed will display updated news from a news website. All I want is the title, date, and basic description of the last three "news posts" inside of a small scrollbox on my website.

**What I can use:**  The news website I want to grab the news from has an RSS Feed ( http://www.wthr.com/category/23903/local-news?clienttype=rss ).

**How do i do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this widget to ypur page.
https://www.rssinclude.com/

Comment: I found this to be the simplest way to get the job done. Thanks a bunch!!!! :]

Comment: You should teach the OP how to achieve this using PHP, not a third-party website (which is down, by the way).

Answer (score 2):

If you have url-file-access enable, just use

```
$result=file_get_contents("http://www.wthr.com/category/23903/local-news?clienttype=rss");
```

To get the content of the URL saved in $result
All you have to do after is to parse the Data in $result.

Comment: can you give me some tutorial on parsing this data?

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516759/how-to-convert-an-rss-xml-feed-in-to-array-using-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google api for it.
Please find url given below..

[Google API for Rss Feed](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#load_feed)

Comment: No matches for "rss" or "feed". You should teach the OP how to achieve this using PHP, not a third-party website.