# xml/rss file creater

Tags: php

```
<channel>
  <title>Company</title>
  <link>http://www.ndroid360.com/companypms/index.php/main_con</link>
  <description>Companypms - By Keyur Modi </description>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <image>
    <title>Company</title>
    <url>http://www.ndroid360.com/companypms/public/admin/dashboard/images/keyur.jpg</url>
    <link>http://www.ndroid360.com/companypms/index.php/main_con</link>
    <width>90</width>
    <height>36</height>
  </image>
  <item>
    <title>Project Add</title>
    <link>http://www.ndroid360.com/companypms/index.php/main_con</link>
    <description>
      OK, modi sarkar
    </description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>A Post Title</title>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.mydomain.com/file-location/</guid>
    <link>http://www.ndroid360.com/companypms/index.php/main_con</link>
    <pubDate>Wed, 30 Apr 2009 23:00:00 +1100</pubDate>
    <description><![CDATA[ <p>This is a brief summary of the post, so tempting that noone  will be able to resist clicking through.</p> ]]></description> 
  </item>
</channel>
```

I want to put an image after second `<item></item>`-tag. What can I do?

Comment: Please improve the question. What second tag?

Comment: As far as I know only one `image`-element is allowed within `channel`. You would leave the specification http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php). Most of these can write back to the feeds as well. And since RSS is XML, it's also a possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/3616044#3616044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only include one top level `<image>` tag in the feed. It's used to identify the feed as a whole, not any of the items.

Comment: ok bro thnx.... i want to know only this. because i m not sure about that...