# open source PHP5-compatible library to parse RSS/Atom

Tags: php, rss

As the title of my question says, I am looking for a library to parse RSS/Atom feeds that is compatible with and exploits the features of PHP **5**. As far as I know, both [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) and [magpie](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) are compatible only with PHP4.

This is related to:
[Best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/250679/825190).
In that question, though, the OP doesn't impose the constraint for the library to be PHP **5** compatible.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with just using SimpleXML?

Comment: @MetalFrog: I thought that would imply rewriting too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimplePie is PHP-5 compatible. It's PHP 4 compatibility is backwards-compatibility. In other words, if you're stuck with an old PHP 4 installation, you can still use SimplePie.

In addition, last time I looked, SimplePie will use more efficient PHP-5 methods if they are available and only fallback to PHP-4 compatibility when necessary.

Comment: Ok. It seems that SimplePie is my choice then. Thanks for your answer, I was wondering exactly whether SimplePie uses PHP-5 methods when available

Answer (score 1):

Look again at new versions of simplepie, its easy to use, oo and has been around since dirt.  I use it and my sites are 5.3

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any cons of using a library that is not PHP5-compatible?