# Load xml from another page

Tags: php, xml, facebook

I'm trying to load this page 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed
in my site with no luck. I'm using this code

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/');
   print_r($xml);

?>
```

but i get many line of error like this

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/:10: parser error :
>   xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /fb_feed/fb_feed.php on line 2

Thanks to all who help me

Comment: Possible dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276656/php-errors-parsing-xml-rss-feed)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a problem with the XML feed itself.

[See this article](http://www.stevenmarkford.com/resolution-xmlparseentityref-noname-xml-error/).

Load the string with file_get_contents, and do a str_replace on the amperand to

```
&amp;
```

So leaving you with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(str_replace('&','&amp;',file_get_contents('https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/')));
```

EDIT:

Just seen in the comments, this has been tackled before and the str_replace can be improved from my original to

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"), array("&", "&amp;"),file_get_contents('https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/')));
```

This avoids converting already correctly encoded ampersands.

EDIT 2 :

Facebook redirects requests from file_get_contents to a browser select page. So we need to 'trick' it into thinking we're using a regular browser.

```
$url='https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/';
$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$ret = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string(str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"),array("&", "&amp;"),$ret));     
var_dump($xml);
```

The first answer should work in most cases, but edit 2 is for the Facebook Dev blog, or any other that redirects based on the user-agent header.

Comment: youre str_replace did indeed fix the problem to load the XML!

Comment: now i have no error but i get the content of facebook main page and not the xml of https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/

Comment: so you get as the result the content of facebook developers blog? it's very strange i copy exactly what you wrote but i get an xml of facebook login page

Comment: Looks like Facebook is redirecting the request, let me see if I can find a way around.

Comment: thanks for your help. This site is able to take the contents http://grabpage.info/h/developers.facebook.com/blog/feed

Comment: with the code of edit 2 i get this error
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /fb_feed/fb_feed.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /fb_feed/fb_feed.php(19): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /fb_feed/fb_feed.php on line 19

Comment: Hi Marco, I've edited the answer load the XML with the str_replace we used previously. The error looks like it's caused by invalid XML, so hopefully that should fix it (I've tested and it works ok for me).

Comment: Thanks again but now i get this result   "bool(false)"

Comment: cURL support  enabled
cURL Information  libcurl/7.12.0 OpenSSL/0.9.7d zlib/1.2.1.1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16409/discussion-between-mark-and-marco-caltagirone)

Answer (score 0):

it could be the case that you need to encode the url as [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) suggests

```
simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/'))
```

if that doesnt work you can try to load the file by `file_get_contents` and pass the returning value to the xml parser:

```
simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents('https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/') );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "https://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed/";
$xml = str_replace('&','&amp;', file_get_contents($url));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
?>
```