# how to display rss api page using php?

Tags: php, parsing, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php)

how I can grab and display the contents of this page?
http://www.journaltocs.ac.uk/api/articles/corrosion+metal

This is a free api, and I want to use it.
I know some xml parsing in php but I need some explanation of this page.

Is that a RSS page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is an RSS page.

There are lots of existing questions that you can look at for further guidance. For example:

[Best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `simplexml_load_file()` be the answer?
And use that function and then print it pretty?