# Looking for Regular Expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm using preg_match function in PHP in order to extract some values from a RSS Feed. Inside this feed content there is something like this:

```
<li><strong>Something:</strong> A text with non alphanumeric characters (more text), more text with non alphanumeric characters (more text)</li>
```

I need to get those "A text with non alphanumeric characters" and "more text with non alphanumeric characters" to save them in a database. I don't know if using regular expressions is the best way to do it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What's the reason for stripping out those chars? And what chars are they?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use a PHP RSS parser and not use regex - some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex (i.e. quick and dirty, not really too maintainable), this will give you the text:

```
$input = '<li><strong>Something:</strong> A text with non alphanumeric characters (more text), more text with non alphanumeric characters (more text)</li>';

// Match between tags
preg_match("#</strong>(.*?)</li>#", $input, $matches);
// Remove the text inside brackets
echo trim(preg_replace("#\s*\(.*?\)\s*#", '', $matches[1]));
```

Though, nested brackets may fail.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on other answers, but beware that buckley's won't work (as they have said, but it might not clear), if it doesn't have exactly one comma.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the structure is always the same you can use this regex

```
</strong>([^,]*),([^<]*)</li>
```

group 1 will have the first fragment, group 2 the other

Once you start parsing html/xml with regexes it becomes quickly apparent that a full blown parser is better suited. For small or throwaway solution you a regex can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<li><strong>Something:</strong> A text with non alphanumeric characters (more text), more text with non alphanumeric characters (more text)</li>';
$str = preg_replace('~^.*?</strong>~', '', $str); // Remove leading markup
$str = preg_replace('~</li>$~', '', $str); // Remove trailing markup
$str = preg_replace('~\([^)]++\)~', '', $str); // Remove text within parentheses
$str = trim($str); // Clean up whitespace
$arr = preg_split('~\s*,\s*~', $str); // Split on the comma
```