# Finding rss feeds in depth2 using php

Tags: php, rss

This is my code:

```
<?php

$location = 'http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com//';
$html = file_get_contents($location);
echo getRSSLocation($html, $location); # http://hakre.wordpress.com/feed/

/**
 * @link http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2002/Jun/03/RSSAuto-DiscoveryPHP
 */
function getRSSLocation($html, $location){
if(!$html or !$location){
return false;
}else{
#search through the HTML, save all <link> tags
# and store each link's attributes in an associative array
preg_match_all('/<link\s+(.*?)\s*\/?>/si', $html, $matches);
$links = $matches[1];
$final_links = array();
$link_count = count($links);
for($n=0; $n<$link_count; $n++){
    $attributes = preg_split('/\s+/s', $links[$n]);
    foreach($attributes as $attribute){
        $att = preg_split('/\s*=\s*/s', $attribute, 2);
        if(isset($att[1])){
            $att[1] = preg_replace('/([\'"]?)(.*)\1/', '$2', $att[1]);
            $final_link[strtolower($att[0])] = $att[1];
        }
    }
    $final_links[$n] = $final_link;
}
#now figure out which one points to the RSS file
for($n=0; $n<$link_count; $n++){
    if(strtolower($final_links[$n]['rel']) == 'alternate'){
        if(strtolower($final_links[$n]['type']) == 'application/rss+xml'){
            $href = $final_links[$n]['href'];
        }
        if(!$href and strtolower($final_links[$n]['type']) == 'text/xml'){
            #kludge to make the first version of this still work
            $href = $final_links[$n]['href'];
        }
        if($href){
            if(strstr($href, "http://") !== false){ #if it's absolute
                $full_url = $href;
            }else{ #otherwise, 'absolutize' it
                $url_parts = parse_url($location);
                #only made it work for http:// links. Any problem with this?
                $full_url = "http://$url_parts[host]";
                if(isset($url_parts['port'])){
                    $full_url .= ":$url_parts[port]";
                }
                if($href{0} != '/'){ #it's a relative link on the domain
                    $full_url .= dirname($url_parts['path']);
                    if(substr($full_url, -1) != '/'){
                        #if the last character isn't a '/', add it
                        $full_url .= '/';
                    }
                }
                $full_url .= $href;
            }
            return $full_url;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
}
```

This code will only find the rss feeds in the current link, but the site has some internal tabs, in which each internal tab has one rss feed. How to modify my code to fetch rss feeds in internal tabs.

Comment: Why do you use regexes to parse that rss? You should use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/250714/1057527)

Comment: Ok, fine I will not use regex, but my problem is not that, I have to find the rss feeds in the internal tabs of the site, can you tell me how is it possible.

Comment: I think there are no developers in stackoverflow to solve this. Sad I dint get any answer to this, thanks