# Displaying the "description" from an RSS/ATOM feed in PHP

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed

I want to know how display the last three "descriptions" from an RSS/ATOM feed on a PHP page.

[(Here is the one I want to fetch something from)](http://www.trevortech.net/resources/twitter/tweetledee/userrss.php)

I am extremely inexperienced with RSS/ATOM feeds and I am not sure if I have word this correctly or if it is even possible.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php. Or you could also use [XMLReader](http://ua1.php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlreader.php) or [SimpleXML](http://ua1.php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php). Here is the example class: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/atom/#box1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: [Best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php). Or you could also use [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlreader.php) or [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php). Here is the example class: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/atom/#box1